# Configuring MySQL to Listen for Remote Connections on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, listener

After I configured MySQL 5.7.20 to listen for remote connections on Ubuntu 17.10 Linux server, the database refused to restart.

I had edited the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and made the following two-line changes *(the bind ip address was intentionally hidden)*:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
bind-address            = ###.###.###.###
require_secure_transport = on
```

The following errors are from journalctl -xe:

```
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
May 01 14:02:58 xweb02 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
May 01 14:02:58 xweb02 audit[12934]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/12934/status" pid=12934 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=126
May 01 14:02:58 xweb02 audit[12934]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=12934 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=0
May 01 14:02:58 xweb02 audit[12934]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/12934/status" pid=12934 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=126
May 01 14:02:58 xweb02 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1525197778.760:435): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/12934/status" pid=12934 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=126
May 01 14:02:58 xweb02 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1525197778.761:436): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=12934 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=0
May 01 14:02:58 xweb02 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1525197778.761:437): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/12934/status" pid=12934 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=126
May 01 14:03:00 xweb02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 01 14:03:28 xweb02 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
May 01 14:03:28 xweb02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 01 14:03:28 xweb02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 01 14:03:28 xweb02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 01 14:03:28 xweb02 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
May 01 14:03:28 xweb02 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
May 01 14:03:29 xweb02 audit[13059]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/13059/status" pid=13059 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=126
May 01 14:03:29 xweb02 audit[13059]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=13059 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=0
May 01 14:03:29 xweb02 audit[13059]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/13059/status" pid=13059 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=126
May 01 14:03:29 xweb02 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1525197809.010:438): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/13059/status" pid=13059 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=126
May 01 14:03:29 xweb02 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1525197809.011:439): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=13059 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=0
May 01 14:03:29 xweb02 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1525197809.011:440): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/13059/status" pid=13059 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=126
May 01 14:03:30 xweb02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 01 14:03:59 xweb02 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
May 01 14:03:59 xweb02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 01 14:03:59 xweb02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 01 14:03:59 xweb02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 01 14:03:59 xweb02 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
May 01 14:03:59 xweb02 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
May 01 14:03:59 xweb02 audit[13182]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/13182/status" pid=13182 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=126
May 01 14:03:59 xweb02 audit[13182]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=13182 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=0
May 01 14:03:59 xweb02 audit[13182]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/13182/status" pid=13182 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=126
May 01 14:03:59 xweb02 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1525197839.260:441): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/13182/status" pid=13182 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=126
May 01 14:03:59 xweb02 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1525197839.260:442): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=13182 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=0
May 01 14:03:59 xweb02 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1525197839.260:443): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/13182/status" pid=13182 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=126 ouid=126
May 01 14:04:01 xweb02 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

If I comment my changes and uncomment the first address-bind, then it works:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
#bind-address            = ###.###.###.###
#require_secure_transport = on
```

Finally, if I uncomment both the first bind-address and the require_secure_transport, and comment the second address-bind, then it works:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
#bind-address            = ###.###.###.###
require_secure_transport = on
```

The problem appears to be with the bind-address line.
Any help with this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The bind-address was set to the private IP address of the server that MySQL is on. It Worked!!!